# Custom layout update per site for one product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a multisite Magento running, and need to add a canonical URL for each product manually.
Since a product can be shown on different sites, each having different navigations, an since the custom layout update is [global], how can I get Magento to apply the custom layout update only if site/shop equals X?

Comment: In the backend (Catalog > Manage Products) you can find a product, change the store scope, and apply a custom layout in the 'Design' tab of the product. But this doesn't apply to the URL - maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I can indeed change the scope to a specific website, but the custom layout update is global, niet store-specific. Therefore, I will need to make a reference to the current store through the XML code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I went to Catalog > manage attributes and set the custom_layout_update scope to store-view.